# Админ Панель где можно изменить имя пользователя

Tags: php, mysql

Есть админ панель где есть данные пользователя надо сделать так что бы при нажати редактировать верхнем поле формы добавлялься значение того пользователя кого я выберал А потом изменить[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Держите, вот, несколько знаков препинания, потом воспользуетесь: ",", ".".

Comment: И код ещё текстом нужно выкладывать, а не картинками